# Oracle JDeveloper Service BUS

Tags: jdeveloper, servicebus, osb

I learning about **OSB** following this [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/sscs/CreatingOSBApp/creating-a-service-bus-app.html#section1).

But in the 
**Defining a Directory Structure and Importing Artifacts -> Import Artifacts -> on number 5 instructions**, there are:

*On the Select WSDL page, click Application Server. Expand DefaultServer, default, and SayHello[Default 1.0], select makegreeting_client_ep(ws) and click OK.  Make sure to avoid the https URL; if it's selected by default, then change it to http using the port 7101.*

But there is no **makegreeting_client_ep** in mine, like this screenshot:

[image]

There are just **SOA -> DefaultServer -> default**, there are no expanding options after that like the documentation.

So what is the possiblity wrong with that..?

I using **Oracle JDeveloper 12c Release 12.2.1.3.0**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the screenshot there is a note saying:

> Note: Oracle WebLogic Server must be started and the SayHello composite application has to be deployed before reaching this step.

At the top of the page in the 'Before You Begin section' it lists some pre-requisites. One of them is:

> The [HelloWorld](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/sscs/CreatingOSBApp/files/helloWorld.zip) composite application deployed in Oracle WebLogic Server